# Shutdown dask workers from client or scheduler

Tags: python, distributed, dask

In the API, there is a way to [restart](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.restart) all workers and to [shutdown](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.shutdown) the client completely, but I see no way to stop all workers while keeping the client unchanged. Is there a way to do this that I cannot find or is it a feature that doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like a feature that does not exist, but is nevertheless doable using the current code. You can use [run_on_scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run_on_scheduler) to interact with the methods of the scheduler itself.

```
workers = list(c.scheduler_info()['workers'])
c.run_on_scheduler(lambda dask_scheduler=None: 
    dask_scheduler.retire_workers(workers, close_workers=True))
```

where `c` is a Client, and we call [retire_workers](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduling-state.html#distributed.scheduler.Scheduler.retire_workers) to gracefully ask each worker to exit.

There are probably other ways to achieve this.
Note that the scheduler remains running in this case - it was not clear from the question if that is desired or not.